# Why would a Saxon Report run correctly on a Mac but not on Windows?

Tags: java, eclipse, saxon

I am using Saxon 4.4.2 to convert DocBook to various formats (e.g. HTML, PDF, ePub).  I am doing development on a MacBook Pro using Eclipse.   Everything is written in Java. On my Mac, everything works fine.  When I use Eclipse to generate a deployable plug-in, copy the plug-in and drop it into my Eclipse installation on Windows 7, and run the conversion from DocBook to HTML, Saxon reports "Failed to compile stylesheet.  1 error detected."

The error comes from

> com.icl.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl, method newTemplates line 120.

called by

> com.icl.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl, method newTransformer, line 72.

My calling line of code is:

```
Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer(xsl);
```

The setting of xsl is done via this line:

```
StreamSource xsl = new StreamSource(DocBookTransformer.class.getResourceAsStream("/lib/docbook-xsl-1.76.1/xhtml/docbook.xsl");
```

Why would Saxon process the stylesheet without error on a Mac, but fail to parse it on Windows, when it is the same Saxon Jars and the same stylesheet file being processed on both machines?

Answer (score 0):

Saxon 4.4.2? Where on earth did you get hold of that? Perhaps a CD in the back of a book published around 1998? It predates the first release on SourceForge in 2001, and was probably designed to run on Java 1.1.8.

So your first step should be to see if the problem still occurs on a more modern release. The current release is 9.5.

The other thing is to find out what the error is that Saxon says it reported. It will have been sent to the JAXP ErrorListener, and unless you changed anything, the default ErrorListener will have written the message to System.err.

The things that are most likely to work on one platform and fail on another are the URIs in xsl:include and xsl:import, so you try checking those.

Comment: I think you must be wrong about the version number. I have no records of a 4.4.2. Both 4.4 and 4.5 were issued around the middle of 1999, before the XSLT 1.0 spec was finalized, and there were many late changes to the spec so the product would be unusable today.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I moved across the US to another state and am just now getting back to this.  I have switched to the current release.  The error I get is:  "Error at xxl: include on line 23…XTSE0165: I/O error reported by XML parser…"  Line 23 is <xsl:include href="../VERSION"/>  VERSION lives on the same level as the folder contain the docbook.xsl file for which the processor is giving back an error.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is case-sensitivity in filenames.